# matlab: fminunc returns 'User objective function returned complex; trying a new point...'

Tags: matlab, machine-learning

fminunc is returning 'User objective function returned complex; trying a new point...' when 'iter-detailed' is on. I know it is because of my cost function, for some reason it is returning a complex component (to be precise it's returning J = NaN + NaNi). Any ideas as to why it is doing this, and how I can fix it?
P.S. I have a very large set features(about 1000), could it be that it's going over the max value or accuracy?
P.s. cost function & gradient:

```
hyp = sigmoid(X * theta);
reg = (lambda/(2*m))*sum((theta(2:end).^2));

J = (1/m * sum((-y .* log(hyp)) - ((1-y) .* log(1-hyp)))) + reg;

grad(1) = (1/m * ((hyp-y)' * X(:,1)))';
grad(2:end) = (1/m * ((hyp-y)' * X(:,2:end)))' + (lambda/m * theta(2:end));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chance you're hitting a weird confluence of bugs where:

- sigmoid(X*theta) is negative OR greater than one (which would give you the complex part when you take its log in line 3 ); and
- either m or y is NaN?

I hadn't noticed this before, but if a NaN interacts with a complex number, you get a "complex" NaN.

```
>> (1+2i) * nan

ans =

      NaN +    NaNi
```

Comment: m is the number of train set, and y is 0 or 1.. so the second part is no, as for the first.. you are on to some thing. Am reading an image file, and for the pixel values, matlab is returning mostly negative values. I need to find out the range so I can scale it to positive values.

Comment: And I am converting RGB to Lab. So that is where the error is coming in.